# Use same compose keys of OSX on Arch

Tags: arch-linux, osx, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I use a apple keyboard and really like the way OSX handle insertion of special characters, for example:

`<Multi_key> + c` then `c` gives `ç`

`<Multi_key> + e` then `e` gives `é`

`<Multi_key> + e` then `a` gives `á`.

But on Arch I'm struggling to find this specific compose file. Is there a pre-build file with these options or will I need to make it myself?

Comment: On my locale `us(altgr-intl)`, I can do the above with `<compose>`, `,`, `c`; `<compose>`, `'`, `e`; `<compose>`, `'`, `a`. Is that satisfactory, or did you want to change them from `,` to `c`, and from `'` to `e`?

Comment: Thanks @Sparhawk, I can use those too, but I'm searching for the specific OSX like, I found they really more obvious than the default `en_US` ones.

Comment: I originally moved from OSX to Linux too, but IMO the default Linux make more sense with time, e.g. the different angled single-quotes for the acute and the grave accent. I'd recommend giving it a longer try, but if you really want, you can manually create `~/.XCompose`, as [per](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/487245/18887) [several](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/103649/18887) [related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197886/18887) [questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/134575/18887).

Answer (score 1):

I and up writing my own compose file to mimic OSX, here it goes to help someone in need. Note that this is the main used speacial chars for Brazilian Portuguese, maybe you have other need but it's easy to add your own keys.

Create a `.XCompose` file on your home with the following content:

```
#this include all the default compose keys on the file
include "%L"

<Multi_key> <c> : "ç"
<Multi_key> <C> : "Ç"
<Multi_key> <e> <a> : "á"
<Multi_key> <e> <A> : "Á"
<Multi_key> <e> <e> : "é"
<Multi_key> <e> <E> : "é"
<Multi_key> <e> <i> : "í"
<Multi_key> <e> <I> : "Í"
<Multi_key> <e> <o> : "ó"
<Multi_key> <e> <o> : "Ó"
<Multi_key> <e> <u> : "ú"
<Multi_key> <e> <U> : "Ú"
<Multi_key> <n> <a> : "ã"
<Multi_key> <n> <A> : "Ã"
<Multi_key> <n> <o> : "õ"
<Multi_key> <n> <O> : "Õ"
<Multi_key> <i> <e> : "ê"
<Multi_key> <i> <E> : "Ê"
<Multi_key> <i> <o> : "ô"
<Multi_key> <i> <O> : "Ô"
```

I just adapted the `ç` to make it a keystroke shorter.